# Generics code not working when i try to return concrete object

Tags: java, generics

The goal i am trying to achieve, is to have different FileLoaders like CSVFileLoader, ExcelFileLoader that can load up any object of type T, as long as it know how to convert using 'C' and create the object of type T. Hope this makes sense.

I am trying to use generics to create a generic FileLoader that will take a Converter of type C and return a List of Object of type T. So I went about creating something like the below but it inst working as expected.

I am getting an error while trying to return object Transaction in the convert method. How should I rewrite this so that it can use generics and I can improve this code to work. I understand there is type erasure, so that is why its complaning in the below code but not sure how to fix it. Please advise

```
//FileLoader takes a converter of type C, Object of type T 
public interface FileLoader<T,C> {    
    List<T> load();
}

//Converter return a list of objects of type T
public interface Converter<T> {
    List<T> convert(Iterable<CSVRecord> csvRecords);
}
```

So with the above interfaces, i tried implementing my classes but clearly I am going wrong, so my understanding isnt great and I would like some help as to where I am going wrong.

```
public class TransactionConverter<T> {

    public List<T> convert(Iterable<CSVRecord> records) {
        List<T> transactions = new ArrayList<>();
        for(CSVRecord r: records){
            T t = convert(r);
            transactions.add(t);
        }
        return transactions;
    }

   private T convert(CSVRecord r){
        //TradeDate,Symbol,Buy/Sell,Quantity,TradePrice
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
        LocalDate transactionDate = LocalDate.parse(r.get(0), formatter);
        String ticker = r.get(1);
        TransactionType transactionType = TransactionType.valueOf(r.get(2));
        Double amount = Double.parseDouble(r.get(3));
        Double quantity =   Double.parseDouble(r.get(4));
        //getting ERROR HERE
        return new Transaction(ticker, "",transactionDate, transactionType, amount, quantity); 
    }
}

public class CSVFileLoader<T,C> implements FileLoader<T,C> {

    private String filePath;
    private TransactionConverter converter;
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CSVFileLoader.class);

    public CSVFileLoader(String filePath, TransactionConverter converter){
        this.filePath = filePath;
        this.converter = converter;
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> load() {
        List<T> transactions = null;
        Reader in = null;
        Iterable<CSVRecord> records;
        try {
            in = new FileReader(filePath);
            records = CSVFormat.RFC4180.withHeader("ID", "CustomerNo", "Name").parse(in);
            transactions =converter.convert(records);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            logger.info("Unable to load file " + filePath);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return transactions;
    }
}
```

Comment: change `public class TransactionConverter<T>` to `public class TransactionConverter implements Converter<Transaction>`.

Comment: That doesnt work, because once I change to Transaction from T, all of generics falls apart in my code, the convert method starts to error out

Comment: why do you have the generic type C in your file loader when it has no use there?

Comment: I am doing it completely incorrectly, my intention is to pass in a Converter of type C, and expect the FileLoader to use that type and return a list of object of type T, so that is why I am passing T,C. I am not using it because I have now screwed up the code completely.

Comment: just read about PECS rule while using generics in java.

Comment: It does work, but you have to change *all* instances of `T` to `Transaction` in your `TransactionConverter` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source code in the question for `TransactionConverter` does not implement the interface `Converter`. Because it's trying to implement it with the concrete type of `Transaction`, it should specify that in the `implements` clause and should not declare a type parameter for itself. It should use the concrete type of `Transaction` anywhere that `T` was used in  `Converter`. Here's the resulting source:

```
public class TransactionConverter implements Converter<Transaction> {

    @Override
    public List<Transaction> convert(Iterable<CSVRecord> records) {
        List<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<>();
        for(CSVRecord r: records){
            Transaction t = convert(r);
            transactions.add(t);
        }
        return transactions;
    }

   private Transaction convert(CSVRecord r){
        //TradeDate,Symbol,Buy/Sell,Quantity,TradePrice
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
        LocalDate transactionDate = LocalDate.parse(r.get(0), formatter);
        String ticker = r.get(1);
        TransactionType transactionType = TransactionType.valueOf(r.get(2));
        Double amount = Double.parseDouble(r.get(3));
        Double quantity =   Double.parseDouble(r.get(4));
        //getting ERROR HERE
        return new Transaction(ticker, "",transactionDate, transactionType, amount, quantity); 
    }
}
```

The type parameter `C` is not used in the `FileLoader` interface, so it is redundant. The fact that a converter is used is an implementation detail of `CSVFileLoader` in this code. Here's the updated interface declaration:

```
public interface FileLoader<T> {
    List<T> load();
}
```

If I understand your intent, `CSVFileLoader` should be able to work with any implementation of `Converter`, but it currently requires a `TransactionConverter`. It also uses the name `transactions` for the list of results, but these might not be `Transaction` objects if another type of `Converter` is used. Here's the updated implementation:

```
public class CSVFileLoader<T> implements FileLoader<T> {

    private String filePath;
    private Converter<T> converter;
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CSVFileLoader.class);

    public CSVFileLoader(String filePath, Converter<T> converter) {
        this.filePath = filePath;
        this.converter = converter;
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> load() {
        List<T> convertedRecords = null;
        Reader in = null;
        Iterable<CSVRecord> records;
        try {
            in = new FileReader(filePath);
            records = CSVFormat.RFC4180.withHeader("ID", "CustomerNo", "Name").parse(in);
            convertedRecords = converter.convert(records);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            logger.info("Unable to load file " + filePath);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return convertedRecords;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for explaining where I am going wrong. I changed the code as suggested, the issue I seeing now is that convertedRecords = converter.convert(records); => convertedRecords is of type List<T> but converter.convert is returning List<Transaction>. saying different types . I dont think casting would be correct here as the FileLoader is agnostic to concrete types. Please advise

Comment: The code I posted compiles correctly, so the problem must be in some other code you didn’t include in the question. It should work as long as you are doing something like `new CSVFileLoader<Transaction>(filePath, new TransactionConverter())` when you create the loader.

Comment: yes I had made the mistake of not having the converter of a generic type  private Converter<T> converter; This was where I had gone wrong. Thanks a lot for letting me know how to fix it